# hasOwnProperty doesn't work on the 'onsubmit' property

Tags: javascript, dom, events

I need to use `hasOwnProperty()` on the `onsubmit` property of an element. However, it's not working:

```
el = document.createElement('a')
<a>​</a>​

// This works as expected
el.onclick2 = (e) => { console.log('click2') }
(e) => { console.log('click2') }
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(el, 'onclick2')
true

// This doesn't
el.onclick = (e) => { console.log('click') }
(e) => { console.log('click') }
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(el, 'onclick')
false
```

Why isn't it working? This is consistent in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It's not an own property

Comment: The trouble is, it *is* its own property. If you check the value of `el.onclick` after the  assignment, you see that it's the function just assigned.

Comment: Own properties are those *directly* set on the object, not coming from the prototype. When you add an arbitrary property like `onclick2` it gets set on the object. `onclick` doesn't because it's not even a regular property [but a pair of a getter and a setter](https://jsbin.com/pijohasade/1/edit?js,console). This is the *why* of why it isn't working. But I'm sure it doesn't actually help you because "*I need to use hasOwnProperty() on the onsubmit property of an element*" is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

I will go with `hasAttribute`, something like:

```js
const hasOnClick = document.querySelector('#myElement').hasAttribute("onclick");
console.log(hasOnClick);
```

```html
<div id="myElement" onclick=""></div>
```